# Java readLine from Com port

Tags: java, serial-port, rxtx

is any way to change this java code (read from com port) to read lines ? 
eg. 

 I'm using rxtx com

original method:

```
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
    switch (event.getEventType()) {
        case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[10];
            int numBytes = 0;
            try {
                while (inputStream.available() > 0) {                       
                    numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(readBuffer));
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use a buffered inputstream which wraps a reader which can wrap your inputstream ... like  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8")); (Where "is" is your inputstream.  Read up on Java IO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `inputStream` is an `InputStream`, you could wrap it with an [`InputStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) and wrap that with a [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)  (that has a [`readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29)). Something like,

```
case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
  String line;
  BufferedReader br = null;
  try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
    try {
      br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

or you could possible use with [try-with-resouces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html),

```
case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
  String line;
  BufferedReader br = null;
  try (br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));) {
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```